# Change label of a form field Django

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a model in `model.py` and I generate a model form in `inventory_form.py`.

A field is named `watercourse` in my model and the form field is labelled `Watercourse`.

`model.py`

```py
class Inventory(models.Model):
    watercourse = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
```

`inventory_form.py`

```py
class InventoryModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Inventory
        fields = ['watercourse',]
        widgets = {
            'watercourse': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'lorem ipsum',
            }),
        }
```

How do I change the label to `Insert a watercourse`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Within the `AuthorForm` class you can set the `labels` attribute which is a dictionary  [maps field name to label](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields).

```
class InventoryModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Inventory
        fields = ['watercourse',]
        widgets = {
            'watercourse': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'placeholder': 'lorem ipsum',
            }),
        }
        labels = {
            'watercourse': 'Insert a watercourse',
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this:

class Meta:

```
labels = {
        'name': 'LabelName',
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In forms.py try

```
labels = {
        'name': _('Writer'),
    }
```